# Populating a ListBox with data from two arrays

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I need assistance with the following:

Populating data from two arrays into a listbox in Visual Studio.

The first array holds date information (EX. 11/2/2020), and the second array will hold discount information (EX. 25% Discount).

So, in the `form load` event the data held in the two arrays should populate in the list box as seen below:

`11/2/2020 = 25% Discount`

and so forth. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim strDates() As String = {"11/2/2020", "11/12/2020", "11/22/2020", "11/30/2020"}
    Dim strDiscount() As String = {"25", "10", "35", "21"}
    Dim intPos As Integer = 0
    
    For Each strDate As String In strDates
        
        strDate += " = " & strDiscount(intPos) & "% Discount"
        ListBox1.Items.Add(strDate)

        intPos += 1

    Next
```

**Results in each item getting:**

```
11/2/2020 = 25% Discount
11/12/2020 = 10% Discount
11/22/2020 = 35% Discount
11/30/2020 = 21% Discount
```

Helpful links:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_arrays.htm

https://www.vbtutor.net/index.php/2018/04/07/adding-items-in-a-listbox/

Answer (score 0):

You could also [Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netframework-4.5.2&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Linq.Enumerable.Zip%60%602);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%253Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue) the arrays together and set that as the `.DataSource` for your ListBox:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim dates() As String = {"11/2/2020", "11/3/2020", "11/4/2020", "11/5/2020"}
    Dim discounts() As Integer = {25, 10, 50, 15}
    Dim entries = dates.Zip(discounts, Function(dt, disc) dt & " = " & disc & "% Discount")
    ListBox1.DataSource = entries.ToList
End Sub
```